# Error in dplyr::summarise(): Caused by error in across()

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, across

I have this code below:

```
library(dplyr)
dfDeplaned <- dfDeplaned %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Activity.Period, GEO.Region, Adjusted.Activity.Type.Code) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(across(c(Adjusted.Passenger.Count), sum))
```

What I want to do is to sum up all the `Adjusted.Passenger.Count` which has the same `Activity.Period`, `GEO.Region` and `Adjusted.Activity.Type.Code` in `dfDeplaned`. For example:

[image]

`200507` `US` `Deplaned` would need to be summed up like: 27271 + 8055 + 36641 and so on.

When I run on my RStudio, this is the output:
[image]

which works perfectly and meets my expectation.

However, when my friend tries to run the code on his RStudio on his laptop, the error below pops up:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: perhaps you friend did not run the entire block but only the last line? or missed a %>%?

Comment: Nope, my friend run the entire block of code just like how I did

Comment: Perhaps your friend has in his environment a variable called `sum` that overrides the function? see `is.function(sum)` if false run rm(sum) and try again